# Why does CORS not seem to work with POST?

Tags: xmlhttprequest, w3c, cors

Mozilla's own [specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control) says simple `GET` or `POST` should be natively CORS's without preflighting but so far every `POST` attempt I've made has resulted in an `OPTIONS` header going out.  When I change it from `POST` to get the code immediately sends a proper `GET` request so the cross site part is working fine.

Here's a slimmed down sample of what I'm doing in firefox:

```
 var destinationUrl = 'http://imaginarydevelopment.com/postURL';
 var invocation = new XMLHttpRequest();
            if (invocation) {
                invocation.open('POST', destinationUrl, true);
                //tried with and without this line
                //invocation.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

                invocation.onreadystatechange = (function Handler() {
                if (invocation.readyState == 4)
                        alert('Request made');
                });
                invocation.send(/* tried with and without data*/);
            }
```

Here's what I already had working in chrome and IE:

```
var destinationUrl = 'http://imaginarydevelopment.com/postURL';
var destination = { url: destinationUrl, type: 'POST', success: AjaxSuccess, error: AjaxError,
            dataType: 'text', contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        };
  destination.data = { 'rows': rowList, 'token': token };
            $jq.ajax(destination);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, I don't know what all contentTypes actually work but `text/plain` does on all 3 browsers:

```
var destination = { url: destinationUrl, type: 'POST', success: AjaxSuccess, error: AjaxError,
             contentType: 'text/plain'
        };
var postData={ 'anArray': theArray, 'token': token };
            destination.data=JSON.stringify(postData);

$jq.ajax(destination);
```

However so far I haven't figured out what's stopping the request from doing anything besides running the success method even when a 505 code is returned. Adding a response header of `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` solved the browser not wanting to read the return data.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_Access_Control

says that the enctype has to be text/plain or you need to use Fx4+
All access headers have to be set correctly