# 403 error on axios head request

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, request, axios

When I make a head request from `axios` to this [url](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/415%2BC2ZrYqL.jpg), it returns a `403 Forbidden` response. It works fine when I make a get request or even when I make a head request from other REST clients like postman. I am guessing it's because CloudFront is trying to deny access from bots. Can I do some workaround so I can get this request to work properly?

```
const axios = require('axios')
axios.head('https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/415%2BC2ZrYqL.jpg')
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.log)
```

Comment: Seems, like a `CORS` issue.. Check out the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header value in your service response (which is giving you the 403 error currently).

Comment: I am not sure but I am guessing that if its a `CORS` issue than neither `get` requests nor `head` requests from same IP should work, right?

Comment: Nope.. You're wrong.. Check this => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563081/why-does-cors-not-seem-to-work-with-post

Answer (score -2):

I dont see a problem in getting the image from stack snippet. Not sure why you are getting `403`

```js
axios.get('https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/415%2BC2ZrYqL.jpg', {
      responseType: 'arraybuffer'
    })
    .then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
    var arrayBuffer = response.data;
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);

    var image = document.getElementById('image');
    image.src = "data:image/jpg;base64," + encode(bytes);
    });
    
// public method for encoding an Uint8Array to base64
function encode (input) {
    var keyStr = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";
    var output = "";
    var chr1, chr2, chr3, enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
    var i = 0;

    while (i < input.length) {
        chr1 = input[i++];
        chr2 = i < input.length ? input[i++] : Number.NaN; // Not sure if the index 
        chr3 = i < input.length ? input[i++] : Number.NaN; // checks are needed here

        enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
        enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
        enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6);
        enc4 = chr3 & 63;

        if (isNaN(chr2)) {
            enc3 = enc4 = 64;
        } else if (isNaN(chr3)) {
            enc4 = 64;
        }
        output += keyStr.charAt(enc1) + keyStr.charAt(enc2) +
                  keyStr.charAt(enc3) + keyStr.charAt(enc4);
    }
    return output;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

<img id="image"/>
```

Comment: I am not getting `403` on `get` requests. Its only `head` requests that fails